# StanfordCoreNLP English upos annotations

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I want to use CoreNLPClient to extract the dependency parser with uPOS annotations.

For now, my code is :

```
def query_NLP_server(my_text, to_print=False):
    '''
    Query the NLP server to tokenize and tag my_text, and do some process to return nice my_tokens
    :param my_text (string): The sentence we want to extract the token and the tags
    :param to_print (boolean): Option to print the resulted tokens extracted from NLP server
    :return: my_tokens (list of list of tuples): The tokens with tags extracted from my_text
    '''

    # 1- Ask the query to the NLP Server
    with CoreNLPClient(annotators=['tokenize', 'ssplit', 'pos', 'parse'],
                       timeout=30000,
                       output_format="json",
                       properties={'tokenize.language': 'en'}
                       ) as client:
        ann = client.annotate(my_text)

    # 2- Process the output of the NLP Server to have a nice token list
    output = ann['sentences'][0]['parse']
    tree = ParentedTree.fromstring(output)
    my_tokens = []
    try:
        for subtree in tree.subtrees(filter=lambda t: t[0].parent().label() == 'ROOT'):
            for subtree2 in subtree:
                my_tokens.append(subtree2.pos())
    except:  # when it is finish (the exception happen when it is ok for us)
        if to_print:
            print('The tokens extracted from NLP Server are :\n', my_tokens, '\n')
    return my_tokens
```

The result I get is :

> [[('I', 'PRP'), ('am', 'VBP'), ('looking', 'VBG'), ('for', 'IN'),
>   ('children', 'NNS'), ('with', 'IN'), ('gingivitus', 'NN'), ('.',
>   '.')]]

But I'd like to **have upos instead of xpos** : it seems possible with the pipeline like explained here : [StanfordNLP Website](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/pos.html#training-only-options)

I already succed with the french model with this code :

```
    with CoreNLPClient(annotators=['tokenize', 'ssplit', 'pos', 'parse'],
                   timeout=30000,
                   output_format="json",
                   properties={'tokenize.language': 'en',
                               'pos.model': 'edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/french/french-ud.tagger',
                               'parse.model': 'edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/frenchFactored.ser.gz'}
                   ) as client:
    ann = client.annotate(my_text)
```

But I don't understand why the 'basic' model in english does not return upos ...
**Is there a way to obtain upos with StanfordCoreNLP Client in English Langage ?**

Answer (score 1):

Not at this time, we haven't trained a part-of-speech tagger for Java Stanford Corenlp for English with that tagset.  I'll add it to the to-do list.

Comment: I can try to train a model today (or soon) and update the models jar.  If you use the latest models jar you could access an English UD model.  It doesn't take a long time/too much effort to train these models.

Comment: Tanks for your anwser ! It would be really great if you could do it ! Sorry I am not so familiar with StanfordNLP what do you mean by UD ( in English UD model) ?

Comment: I mean UPOS from UD 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

You can use this simple conversion https://universaldependencies.org/tagset-conversion/en-penn-uposf.html

However, as Dr. Manning commented here https://github.com/UniversalDependencies/docs/issues/212#issuecomment-148846154 , "there are a number of instances where a translation from XPOS just isn't possible without seeing syntactic context."

### Option 2

To make a better conversion, follow
https://github.com/clulab/processors/wiki/Converting-from-Penn-Treebank-to-Basic-Stanford-Dependencies

You will need to prepare the text in a tree structure. Each line consists of a tree of a sentence. For example,

```
(S1 (S (S (S (NP (JJ Anti-Ro-LRB-SSA-RRB-) (NNS autoantibodies)) (VP (VBP are) (VP (VBN associated) (PP (IN with) (NP (NP (NN T) (NN cell) (NN receptor) (NN beta) (NNS genes)) (PP (IN in) (NP (JJ systemic) (NN lupus) (NN erythematosus) (NNS patients))))))) (. .)))))  
(S1 (S (S (S (NP (NP (JJ Several)) (PP (IN of) (NP (NP (DT the) (ADJP (ADJP (JJ heterogeneous)) (ADJP (JJ clinical))) (NNS manifestations)) (PP (IN of) (NP (JJ systemic) (NN lupus) (NN erythematosus)))))) (VP (VBP have) (VP (VBN been) (VP (VBN associated) (PP (IN with) (NP (JJ specific) (NP (NNS autoantibodies))))))) (. .)))))
```

Convert the file with the following line

```bash
java -cp "*" -mx1g edu.stanford.nlp.trees.EnglishGrammaticalStructure -basic -keepPunct -conllx -treeFile treebank > treebank.conllx
```